# Three perpendicular vectors, one has unknown directional cosines

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, geometry

I need help figuring out this textbook excersise. I know the relations:

$$\hat{a} \cdot \hat{c} = 0$$

$$\hat{b} \cdot \hat{c} = 0$$

and

$$\alpha{}^2 + \beta{}^2 + \gamma{}^2= 1$$

but am still a bit stuck. Could someone help please?

Two vectors $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ have the directional cosines as:
$$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0\right) \ \ and \ \ \left(0, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{-1}{2}\right)$$ respectivly.

A third vecotr, $\hat{c}$, is perpendicular to both $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$.

What are the directional cosines of $\hat{c}$?

Comment: Welcome to SE. While this could very well be part of a physics exercise, this question has nothing to do with physics, it's just trigonometry. You should post thins in the [math site](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Here's a hint : The vector $\hat {c}$ is along $\hat{a}  \times \hat{b}$.

Comment: @Cross your username has never been more relevant

Comment: @Holly Bee What is alpha, beta, and gamma? The components of vector c?